# RDTSC (profiling) NASM syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, profiling, nasm, rdtsc

I want to calculate the clock cycles of CPU required to run my program using `rdtsc` instruction as it is required in my assignment.
What should be the syntax to use `rdtsc` instructions in "AFD"?
I'm using `rdtsc` instruction as it is but "AFD" terminates my program as it gets executed...

Comment: You forgot to show your code and what the actual error is. See [mcve] and learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I'm using 'rdtsc' instruction in my code ... afd giving no error but but it ends my program instead of fetching the the clock cycles

Answer (score 2):

The `rdtsc` instruction has no operands at all. So that's certainly not the issue.

But many environments don't allow the use of this instruction by user programs.
e.g. Windows doesn't allow 16-bit DOS programs to use `rdtsc`

Probably this also holds for "AFD" that you are using.